# Python: Consolidating sublists; spanning multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists, sublist

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
[u'https://www.microsoft.com']
[u'https://www.microsoft.com']
[u'https://products.office.com/en-us/home']
[u'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/']
[u'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us']
[u'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

I want to clean up the output a bit, sort the values, remove duplicate entries, and so on. But in it's current format, instead of operating on each values as an entire individual element, it's operating on individual characters (i.e. just a string of individual letters). What I get back is just nonsensical diced up strings of text.

So basically, I want to consolidate all the sublists into a single list, on a single line, in the following (regular) format:

```
['https://www.microsoft.com', 'https://www.microsoft.com', 'https://products.office.com/en-us/home', 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/', 'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us', 'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

---

I'm new to Python, so there's a chance I've missed something (or used incorrect terminology at some point), but this (and the placement of the square brackets) is why I assumed this to be considered a list (and/or multiple sublists); if I substitute `print(links)` with `print(type(links))`, I get the following output:

```
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
<type 'list'>
```

---

The original piece of code where `links` is defined, looks something like this:

```
class LinkParser(HTMLParser):
  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    links = []
    if tag == 'a':
      for attr in attrs:
        if attr[0] == 'href':
          links.append(attr[1])
          print(links)
```

Comment: the output of `print(my_list)` does not look like a list...

Comment: Could you give the output of `type(my_list)` ?

Comment: You probably want list(set([el[0] for el in my_list])).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Because of the newlines?

Comment: newlines, no commas, missing brackets around the outer list.

Comment: @LaurentH. Sure, I've added it to the question.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist It's exactly as it appears in the question; without commas, etc.

Comment: then it's not a python list (or your print function is modified... the output of `print(type(my_list))` is also weird...). what is the definition of `my_list`?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I've added some more information to the question.

Comment: @JoonatanSamuel That just returns the first character from each sublist. "`h`" in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

1. The object/list in question (i.e. **`links`**), needs to be initialized outside the scope of the function and/or class in which it's defined (i.e. the block of code where items are appended to it). It can come before, or after; as long as long as it's interpreted first.
2. The same applies to calling the **`print()`** statement (regarding scope), but it should be interpreted last (after calling the function and/or class that sets it up).

---

**For example:**

### Input:

```
class LinkParser(HTMLParser):
  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'a':
      for attr in attrs:
        if attr[0] == 'href':
          links.append(attr[1])

links = []
LinkParser().feed(html)
print(links)
```

### Output:

```
[u'https://www.microsoft.com', u'https://www.microsoft.com', u'https://products.office.com/en-us/home', u'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/', u'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us', u'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a list of list in my_list. If so

```
l = [['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://products.office.com/en-us/home'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us'],
['https://www.xbox.com/en-us']]

res = []
for i in l:
    if i[0] not in res:
        res.append(i[0])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.microsoft.com', 'https://products.office.com/en-us/home', 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/', 'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us', 'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

Answer (score 0):

`toolz.concat` is surprisingly efficient (as a lazy function) and elegant for this kind of task.

```
from toolz import concat

lst = [['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://products.office.com/en-us/home'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us'],
['https://www.xbox.com/en-us']]

list(concat(lst))  # for a sorted list, replace list with sorted

# ['https://www.microsoft.com',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com',
#  'https://products.office.com/en-us/home',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us',
#  'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

Or, if you want a set:

```
set(concat(lst))

# {'https://products.office.com/en-us/home',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/',
#  'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us',
#  'https://www.xbox.com/en-us'}
```

If you don't have `toolz`, you can use the below instead. `toolz` often provides easy access for some common hard-to-find functions hidden in other libraries.

```
import itertools
itertools.chain.from_iterable(...)
```

Comment: `toolz` is not in the standard python library. you might want to add a link to the library and how to install it.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, updated with `itertools` alternative. `toolz` often just provides syntax sugar, or shortcuts to commonly used tools.

Comment: nothing against `tools`. i just thought the answer would be more complete if you added some information about the library.

Comment: I haven't used `toolz` but I tried the `set` and `itertools` techniques that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://www.microsoft.com'],
['https://products.office.com/en-us/home'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/'],
['https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us'],
['https://www.xbox.com/en-us']]

from itertools import chain

new_list = list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(data)))

print(new_list)
>>>
['https://www.microsoft.com',
 'https://products.office.com/en-us/home',
 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/',
 'https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us',
 'https://www.xbox.com/en-us']
```

Answer (score 0):

you not have a single list, but 6 lists with one element. if you want to collect
all that into one item without duplicates i suggest you use a
[`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set):

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        my_set = set()
        if tag == 'a':
            for attrs in attrs:
                if attrs[0] == 'href' and '.' in attrs[1]:
                    my_set.add(attrs[1])
        print(sorted(my_set))
```

...i was not able to test that; you may have to tweak it a litte.

Comment: Same problem. The output looks like several lines of this: `['.', '/', ':', 'c', 'f', 'h', 'i', 'm', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'w']`

Comment: really? because: `my_set = set(); my_set.add('hello')` gives `{'hello'}`...

Comment: That was using `.update`. With `.add`, the output looks identical to how it is in the question. My brain hurts.

Comment: do you use all of that in yet another loop?

Comment: Nope. No more loops. I even tried omitting the current `for` loop, which I thought would work, but there was no output.

Comment: that is strange... the print statement is outside the for loop; it should be executed once only.

Comment: If I remove the indent before the `print` statement like you have, it makes a mess. Well, it's almost identical, but it has a bunch of blank lines randomly throughout the regular text.

Comment: sorry, then i can't help. you'd have to strip down your code to the absolute minimum and also provide absolutely minimal input you pass to your command. otherwise i can only guess at what your input is and that is obviously not good enough. sorry.